# Delete multiple weekly entries in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large number of data on excel and the date when the data came in is present in column C. I am trying to come up with a way to delete double entries in any week. I tried the following VBA code but it didn't work. Would really appreciate if I can get some help.

```
Sub deltrial()

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim i As Range

Dim j As Range


Set rng1 = Range("B2:B58")
Set rng2 = Range("B3:B59")

For Each i In rng1
For Each j In rng2

If j.Value - i.Value < 6 Then

j.ClearContents
End If

Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you use Remove Duplicates that's on the data tab?

Comment: You write "data came in is present in column C" but your code is referencing column B: where's the truth? And also show an example of your data before and after desired code behavior

Comment: I don't think I was very clear with this. The entries aren't duplicate, all we want is to make sure we get one entry per week. So the entry before lets say todays entry, we should have gotten at least 7 days ago

Answer (score 0):

The RemoveDuplicates method can be called in VBA, something like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$8").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: The duplicates are within the same week but not on the same date, so I don't think excel will be able to pick up that they are repeated

Comment: If the day of the week is in Column A, and the potentially duplicate data is in column B, then the code is:  `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$4").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlNo`

Comment: That will remove both column A and B when there is a duplicate in B.